# Assigning from with asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, scope, async-await

I have a `server.js` file in which I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

let driver;

(async () => {    
  try {
    driver = await someAsyncFunction();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();

const port = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}.`);
});

module.exports = {
  app,
  driver,
};
```

However, the value of `driver` is undefined outside of the async function. How can I correctly assign a value to `driver` outside of the async function?

Comment: you can't. module exports happens synchronously and do not re-evaluated if consumer imports it early. You should export awaitable instead and let consumer asynchronously wait for value.

Comment: You can't. Just don't. At best, export a promise.

Comment: @OJKwon can you explain what you mean by "you should export awaitable instead"?

Comment: Any value is "awaitable" in JavaScript (`await 5`) is perfectly valid. I think he means you should export a "Promise"